# AWS EventBridge - is it able to include tag value of instance in the Rule Pattern & the output

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

#### Here is a sample event pattern

```
{
  "source": ["aws.ec2"],
  "detail-type": ["EC2 Instance State-change Notification"],
  "detail": {
    "state": ["terminated"]
  }
}
```

Would it possible to include tag values of specific instance in the detail and get pass those tag values into the Input message send to the target?

Currently I am using Input Transfomrer with following configuration

###### Input configuration

```
{"account":"$.account","instance-id":"$.detail.instance-id","region":"$.region","state":"$.detail.state","time":"$.time"}
```

```
"At <time>, the status of your EC2 instance <instance-id> on account <account> in the AWS Region <region> has changed to <state>."
```

###### Ouptut message

```
"At 2022-01-26T00:29:41Z, the status of your EC2 instance i-0ae54c6931ad72f12 on account XXXXXX in the AWS Region us-west-2 has changed to terminated."
```

###### Prefer Message

```
"At 2022-01-26T00:29:41Z, the status of your EC2 instance name ABC-XYZ on account XXXXXX in the AWS Region us-west-2 has changed to terminated."
```

Comment: It should depend on your event. In the question it doesn't seem this is your whole event. How do you get account from the sample event? Emit whole event`(Matched ebent)` and if you have tags there then yes(most probably not) and if not, then you can't.

Comment: @Riz: The output message is from actual message from EventBridge with SNS services as its target. So if you would it to included the tag for example the `InstanceName` how would you do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
    {"version":"0","id":"ef80b5de-5221-c559-b5c3-590c4dfgb8bf","detail- 
    type":"EC2 Instance State-change    
    Notification","source":"aws.ec2","account":"xxxxxx","time":"2022-01-    
    26T11:24:35Z","region":"xxxx","resources":["arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-    
    1:xxxxx:instance/i-082xxxxxx"],"detail":{"instance-id":"i-    
    082xxxxx","state":"terminated"}}
```

This is the event you get when you don't use `Input Transformer` and use `Matched event`. It means you can get only the values present here. So you question about `InstanceName` is not possible as you can see it's not present in the event.
You have to send the `instance-id` you get from your `input transformer` to a lambda which does `aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids instance-id(this is the one you get from input transformer)` which will give you all the tags and this lambda can then send an `sns`.